# How to assign different color to even rows in grid in atk 4.2.1

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

even css class does not seem to work in 4.2.1 to assign a different color to even rows,
is there a new method to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`tr:even` is a CSS property, you can use that. If you want HTML support, you can submit a patch with that capability.